# scheduled checking on file in remote linux server

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks

I need to check my scheduled jobs in remote linux server for its status. Usually the success would be indicated by a ${Taskname}_YYMMDDhhmm.ok file. Because the jobs were scheduled several times a day, so there would be many ok file for a task.

The jobs could be initialed by other remote machine by remote shell script, or they could be initialed by cron.

```
Example schedule:
Taskname   Scheduled_Start_Time
Task A  00:00
        06:00
        12:00
Task B  09:30  
Task C  **:30 (every 30 minutes)
Task D  09:30
```

So I would like to make a quick and dirty program which can be scheduled to check on some file over a remote server. And I would like to install it and make it a daemon as a task on my Windows xp . Would you please recommend any programming language?

For example, I know Task B and D would only run once a day, so I can check their ok file by 11:30am. I would configure my program and I would input the time to check, what file to check ( by regular expression on the data and time ) and where it should be located. Remember it would be on remote linux server.

```
To sum up, the requirement for the programming language/tools:
1) it have library for scheduling some task
2) it can check a file's existence on a remote machine
3) it can be set as a daemon
4) it is okay with windows
5) (optional) After I list every scheduled tasks for this program, it can have a gui to indicate the job's status with some green/red color.
```

Every opinions would be appreciated. Thanks! If there are some existing tool, I would really appreciate the one who tolds me!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using PHP.

1. You can manage cron jobs using /var/spool/cron/crontabs/ folder on most standard cron daemon. Each file in this folder is named after the username who has created it.
2. PHP have SSH connection support, so you can connect and do you stuff using it. Be it for file manipulation, restarting daemon or something else. For more information, please check: http://php.net/manual/en/book.ssh2.php
3. You can have PHP application set as a daemon easily. In fact, you can have almost any executable set as a service in linux :)
4. PHP is crossplatform, so you wont have any issues running it from a windows box.
5. For a GUI you can use the php-gtk extension. I've never tried it, but it seem okay.
   Check http://gtk.php.net/ for more information on this.